# Spring security validate captcha via filter has wrong value

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, captcha

I'm working on Spring Boot, using spring security for auth login. I finished this part. Now, I'd like to implement captcha in login page. I did it but sometimes value went wrong. Here my source code.

**Login page**

```
<form th:action="@{/j_spring_security_check}" method="post">
<tr>
                <th align="left" width="30%">
                    <label for="userId">User Id</label>
                </th>
                <td width="70%">

                    <input type="text" style="width: 150px" name="userId" autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="left" width="30%">
                    Password
                </th>
                <td width="70%">

                    <input type="PASSWORD" style="width: 150px" name="password" autocomplete="off"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th align="left" width="30%">
                    Answer
                </th>
                <td width="70%">
                    <input type="text" name="logonAnswer" style="width: 150px"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right">&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td align="left">
                    <div id="captcha"
                         style="cursor: pointer; height: 30px; width: 150px; display: inline-block; float: left"><img
                            th:src="@{/captcha}"/></div>
                    <div id="captchaRefresh" class="refresh-btn" title="Click to get other Captcha"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
</form>
```

**In security config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;
    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired
    private CaptchaFilter captchaFilter;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new CustomerPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/configuration/**").hasRole(roleRepository.getRolesByGroup("USER"))
                .antMatchers("/configuration/**", "/merchant/**", "/import/**", "/manualSettle/**", "/report/**", "/user/**").hasAnyRole(roleRepository.getRolesByGroup("ADMIN"))
                .antMatchers("/superadmin").hasRole(roleRepository.getRolesByGroup("SUPERADMIN"))
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .usernameParameter("userId")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .failureUrl("/login?error")
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(captchaFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
    }
}
```

**In captcha validation filter**

```
@Autowired
    UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (userDetailsService != null
                && request.getParameter("logonAnswer") != null
                && !request.getParameter("logonAnswer").equals("")
                && session != null && request.getParameter("logonAnswer").equalsIgnoreCase(session.getAttribute("wirecardmposcaptcha").toString())) {
            userDetailsService.setCaptchaOK(true);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

**And in userDetailsImplement**

```
private boolean captchaOK;

    public void setCaptchaOK(boolean captchaOK) {
        this.captchaOK = captchaOK;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Users user = userRepository.findByUserId(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("UserId or Password invalid");
        }

        if (!captchaOK)
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("Invalid Captcha");

        Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Roles> roles = user.getRoles();
        for (Roles role : roles) {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRoleName()));
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserId(), user.getPassword(), user.getEnabled().equals("true"), true, true, true, grantedAuthorities);
    }
```

**So in login controller:**

```
private String getErrorMessage(HttpServletRequest request, String key) {

        Exception exception = (Exception) request.getSession().getAttribute(key);

        String error = "";
        if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            error = "Invalid user ID and password!";
        } else if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            error = "User is locked";
        } else if (exception instanceof InternalAuthenticationServiceException) {
            error = "Invalid answer.";
        } else {
            error = "Invalid user ID and password!";
        }

        return error;
    }
```

So, I debug in captcha filter the value of captchaOk change many times. Not sure am I doing correct way.

Please take a look on it and give comments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I customized a filter to verrify the captcha in spring boot application before. Maybe something wrong with your customized filter. You can refer to my implementations:

1.CaptchaAuthenticationFilter: put verification code in session when creating it, then take it from session to verify here.

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * The filter to verify captcha.
 */
public class CaptchaAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private String processUrl;

    public CaptchaAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl, String failureUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        this.processUrl = defaultFilterProcessesUrl;
        setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureUrl));
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse res=(HttpServletResponse)response;
        if(processUrl.equals(req.getServletPath()) && "POST".equalsIgnoreCase(req.getMethod())){
            String expect = req.getSession().getAttribute("YZM").toString();

            //remove from session
            req.getSession().removeAttribute("YZM");

            if (expect != null && !expect.equals(req.getParameter("verifyCode"))){
                unsuccessfulAuthentication(req, res, new InsufficientAuthenticationException("Wrong verification code."));
                return;
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

2.Configure it to spring security:

```
 @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        // add filter here
        http.addFilterBefore(new CaptchaAuthenticationFilter("/login", "/login?error2"), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/index").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/message/*").hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/index").failureUrl("/login?error1").permitAll()
                .and().rememberMe().tokenValiditySeconds(60*60*7).key("message")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();
    }
```

3.Note the failureUrl `/login?error2` above. If the captcha verifies fail, then the request would be redirected there. You can capture the error on the page like this:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div th:if="${param.error1}">
        <div class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
            <i class="icon-bolt bigger-110"></i>
            Wrong username or password!
        </div>
    </div>

    <div th:if="${param.error2}">
        <div class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">
            <i class="icon-bolt bigger-110"></i>
            Wrong verification code!
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```